# Log file is not giving the desired result, cannot find the error in the code

Tags: python, logging

I am creating three log files for each region like below. If the `region1` is present in filename then its status whether its transferred or failed will be shown in `'region1.log'` similarly for `region2` and `region3`. I am transferring files from one folder to another.

```
import os
from os import path
import shutil
import logging
import paramiko

formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s[%(filename)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s') 

def setup_logger(name, log_file, level=logging.INFO):
    handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)        
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(level)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger


src = "source_path"
dst = "destination_path"
files = os.listdir(src)

for i in files:
    if 'region1' in i:
       logger1 = setup_logger('',"region1.log" )

        #print(i)
       try:
            filename = os.path.join(src, i)
            shutil.move(filename, dst)
            logger1.info(i + '   tranferred')
       except:
            logger1.error(i + '   failed')


    elif 'region2' in i:
        logger2 = setup_logger('',"region2.log" )

        #print(i)
        try:
            filename = os.path.join(src, i)
            shutil.move(filename, dst)
            logger2.info(i + '   tranferred')
        except:
            logger2.error(i + '   failed')

    elif 'region3' in i:
        logger3 = setup_logger('',"region3.log" )

        #print(i)
        try:
            filename = os.path.join(src, i)
            shutil.move(filename, dst)
            logger3.info(i + '   tranferred')
        except:
            logger3.error(i + '   failed')

    else:
        print(i)
```

The issue is:

In `region1.log` `region2.log` `region3.log` its printing status of all three regions whereas according to code for `region1.log`  `if 'region1' in i:` it should give the status as transferred or failed for region1 only.

Where am i going wrong? Please help!!!

Comment: You're using the same name in all your `getLogger()` calls, since `name` is always an empty string. So you're adding all the file handlers to the same logger object, so it logs everything to all 3 files.

Comment: yeah! got my mistake, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give different names when calling `setup_logger()`. If you give the same name each time, `logging.getLogger()` will return the same logger object, and you'll just add another handler to it when you call `logger.addHandler()`. Since the logger logs to all its handlers, all the messages end up in all the files.

You can also remove all the identical code in the cases for each region, and do that in one place.

```
for i in files:
    if 'region1' in i:
        logger = setup_logger('region1', 'region1.log')
    elif 'region2' in i:
        logger = setup_logger('region2', 'region2.log')
    elif 'region3' in i:
        logger = setup_logger('region3', 'region3.log')
    else:
        print(i)
        continue

    try:
        filename = os.path.join(src, i)
        shutil.move(filename, dst)
        logger.info(i + '   tranferred')
    except:
        logger.error(i + '   failed')
```